# SEO - Temporary unpublished pages - Which http status code to return?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes, http-status-code-307

In my CMS there are some pages that are temporary unpublished and later re-published. From a SEO perspective which is the best way to handle them. Tell the search engines to remove them, or that they are temporary moved?

Not all pages are always republshed, in some case the status code returned will not be the best option, but I guess it makes more sense to handle in the right way the ones that are going to be re-publised than the ones that will never be.

Which status to return when a user or a search engine try to surf to this page?
302? 
307? 
404? 
Or which is the best way to handle this scenario?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some suggest using a `503` for reasons explained here:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Take-Down-Your-Website-Temporarily-Without-Affecting-Google-Ranking-246829.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeremyJStarcher just one question. The article states that the page with a 503 will drop it's rate but will get it back only if it is a **transient** event. The problem my pages are not always published again after a short period, then I am risking google to take them away.

Comment: That I can't answer.  I had looked this stuff in context of taking my website down for a protest.  Other than what I read there, I know nothing.